# How to import package modules from package's __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have a list of module name what I want to import from `__init__.py`.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/pkg
$ touch /tmp/__init__.py /tmp/pkg/{a.py,b.py}
$ cat /tmp/pkg/__init__.py
to_import = ["a", "b"]

import importlib
for toi in to_import:
    importlib.import_module(toi)

$ cd /
$ python
>>> import tmp.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tmp/pkg/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    importlib.import_module(toi)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named a
>>>
```

python 2.7.4 Ubuntu 64-bit

***Question***: So how do I import package modules from package's `__init__.py`?

Comment: Okay, I don't get it. Why not just do `import a, b`?

Comment: I'm minimized the example for simplicity. The module list is dynamic and obtained elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [relative imports](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for this.  Try to change `/tmp/pkg/__init__.py` to the following:

```python
to_import = [".a", ".b"]

import importlib
for toi in to_import:
    importlib.import_module(toi, __name__)
```

Notice dots before module names and second argument to `import_module` function.

Comment: ...or just use a simple import statement as the language intends. This is a super complicated to do something easy.

Comment: ..but topic starter specifically asked about importing all modules from a list.  Also, with `import` statement you nevertheless need to use relative imports in this scenario, like `from . import a, b`.

Comment: `import a,b` is a list and its the normal way to import from a \_\_init\_\_.py file. You don't need "from ." or "." anything. "." is used for relative imports among package modules, but not \_\_init\_\_.py itself.

Comment: Indeed, `import a, b` works there.  Few minor points: I believe that there are no difference between relative imports from `__init__.py` and from other package modules; in python 2.7 you can use for that both syntaxes: with or without a dot (unless there is `from __future__ import absolute_import` statement); and relative imports without a dot were deprecated in python 3.

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thanks Kirill! I new I was close :)

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Still getting an "ImportError: No module named moduleName" with or without the dot in the parameter passed to import_module

Answer (score 1):

You must add the **init** at the end

```
import tmp.pkg.__init__
```

The imports should be in the same path as the **init**.py file otherwise they will not work

```
FullPath/pkg/__init__.py
```

init.py file

```
to_import = ["__HistogramObjects__"]

import importlib
for toi in to_import:
    importlib.import_module(toi)
```

Then in your file that you want to import from

```
import FullPath.pkg.__init__ as im

for i in im.to_import:
    print i
```

Your output should be:

```
__HistogramObjects__
```